# How to capture workload from production to replay on test?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to perform performance testing on my test server.

How can I capture workload from production and replay on my test server?

Basically I'm looking for detailed steps so that I can replay the workload from production to my test environment.

Answer (score 5):

You can record the production workload with SQL Server Profiler and [replay](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190995%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) it against the test environment. There might be a bottleneck because the Profiler only replays from one computer. If you need more load from several computers (and have SQL Server 2012) you could use [Distributed Replay](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878183.aspx) (as long as you don't run into the same bugs with TVPs in traces as I've run into).

Note: the distributed replay requirement for SQL 2012 is for the replay client, you can use a 2008 trace file and target a 2008 instance if you want. See [Distributed replay requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878239.aspx)